# Armature Moves Mesh in Object Mode, but in Pose Mode Body Doesn't Move?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature, pose-mode

So I had this basic cube mesh design that I created and joined everything together using ctrl + j. When I symmetrize my bones and add automatic weights, all the bones rotate fine, but for some reason the body of my character doesn't move when I move the spine.

Here's the original

[image]

Then when I try to move the armature

[image]

What could cause the body of my character to not move when I move the spine bone??

Comment: It not influenced by that bone. You can check it in Weight Paint mode or at the vertex groups in Edit mode.

Comment: ah it was a weight paint issue